# Populate a list from JSON data

Tags: json, list, sapui5

I am using javascript in sapui5. I have JSON data as `{0:"A",1:"B",2:"C"}`. I want to populate a list with the data. How can I do that?

Comment: You want separate list for keys and values??

Comment: What is your expected output? What have you tried to achieve it so far?

Comment: I want that the strings A,B,C to appear in my list. Since there is no key value pair, I am finding it difficult to bind it to the list

Comment: thats because you are giving a dictionary instead of an array. Change your data as `["A","B","C"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the list was like below:

```
<List id="listId" items="{/}">
    <StandardListItem title="{0}"/>
</List>
```

and

```
var oYourData = {
    0: "A",
    1: "B",
    2: "C"
};
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oYourData);
this.getView().byId("listId").setModel(oModel);
```

Output:

[image: sample list with only title]

Assume your list like this:

```
<mvc:View
  controllerName="sap.m.sample.ListCounter.List"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m">
  <List
    headerText="Products"
    items="{
      path: '/ProductCollection'
    }" >
    <StandardListItem
      title="{Name}"
      counter="{Quantity}"/>
  </List>
</mvc:View>
```

sample oData should look like:

```
var oData = {
    "ProductCollection": [
        {
            "ProductId": "1239102",
            "Name": "Power Projector 4713",
            "Quantity": 3,
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "2212-121-828",
            "Name": "Gladiator MX",
            "Quantity": 10,
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "K47322.1",
            "Name": "Hurricane GX",
            "Quantity": 25,
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "22134T",
            "Name": "Webcam",
            "Category": "Accessory",
            "Quantity": 22,
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "P1239823",
            "Name": "Monitor Locking Cable",
            "Category": "Accessory",
            "Quantity": 30,
        }
    ]
}
```

Read more about Models and Binding [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/91f0ca956f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html)

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't shown your list definition, I can only concentrate on the data in your question, and assume for the sake of this question that you are talking about a List control in, say, the sap.m library, for example.

The issue you will be facing is that the structure that your data has doesn't fit with the expected structure that is used when binding to an aggregation such as the List control's items aggregation. You need an array, rather than an object.

So this becomes a JavaScript data question. To convert your structure (which we'll assume is in a variable called mData) into something more appropriate for an aggregation binding, you could do something like this:

`Object.keys(mData).map(function(k, i) { return { key: k, value: mData[k] }; })`

which will give you an array like this:

`[ { key: '0', value: 'A' },
  { key: '1', value: 'B' },
  { key: '2', value: 'C' } ]`

You can then bind this.

If you want further help doing the actual binding, you'll need to make a bit more of an effort in your question and supply the control definitions you're using. Show us the code, help us help you.